# How could I simulate the following scenario in JMETER?

Tags: multithreading, performance, testing, jmeter

I want to do the following:

-20 users log into the application.
-The users have to remain connected to the session, but each 20 minutes they have to make an specific request to the page.
-I would like to measure the time of the last request for each user after being connected the 2 hours and making the specific request each 20 minutes.

Which thread group or actions will be recomendable?

Comment: could you elaborate on `The users have to remain connected to the session`

Comment: Hi..! Rahul...! The users have to login and they have to remain connected the two hours into the system, during that two hours they have to make an specific post http request each 20 minutes, in the last request I want to measure the time that each user is taking to make that last request. I hope this help to clarify

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and configure it as follows:

   [image]

   where:

   - `20` - is the number of connected users
   - `6` - is the number of iterations (user makes a request each 20 minutes == 3 requests per hour == 6 requests per 2 hours)
2. Add [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)
3. Add sampler(s) performing the login under the Once Only Controller. This way the users will perform the login only once
4. Add HTTP Request sampler which you're going to run each 20 minutes below the Once Only Controller
5. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) as a child of the HTTP Request and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (vars.get('__jm__Thread Group__idx') != '5') {
       prev.setIgnore()
   }
   ```

   this will instruct JMeter to not to record first 5 iterations metrics, only last one will be recorded.
6. Add Flow Control Action sampler and configure it to sleep for `1200000` milliseconds (20 minutes)

Test plan overview:

[image]